# How to limit the results reading a xml in blocks for an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, sdk

I'm loading content from an xml which is quite heavy and slow to load because it must load several images for a listing.

This may take several seconds and I would load it into pieces, such as load 10 results and give an option to load other 10 results, as if it were the page of a website.

An example of what I'd do is for example the Facebook application, which loads certain inputs and gives the option to load older ones.

Now I'm loading the contest as follows:

I've created a NSThread which calls a function that has a NSAutoreleasePool, which reads the xml and creates the list one by one with a for case.

Can anyone guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use ASIHTTPRequest to download the image from url. for example

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
if (!request) return;
request.timeOutSeconds = 5;
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
[requestArray addObject:request];
```

it will start downloading image, it has delegate method called request finished from that we load image.